# Ruby on Rails AJAX modal doesn't show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with AJAX modal window. It just shows grey background, but view doesn't appear.

Link to modal window:

```
<%= link_to "Create Message", messages_path, remote: true,  data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#ajax-modal" } %>

<%= render 'messages/create' %>
```

Modal window (_create.html.erb):

```
<div id="ajax-modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">

  <div class='modal-header'>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3 class="modal-title">Žinutės siuntimas</h3>
  </div>

  <div class='modal-body'>
    <div class="modal-body-content"></div>
    <div class="ajax-loader"></div>
  </div>

  <div class='modal-footer'>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Atšaukti</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

After I click on link, grey transparent background appears, but doesn't show modal window...

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Try [Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint)-ing your page next time; it would have caught this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML for your modal is malformed, you are missing the modal-content and modal-dialog divs.

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

[Check this out for more information.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)